# How to unit test a dynamic website that renders templates?

Tags: html, node.js, unit-testing, express, web-testing

My controllers end in rendering a template and giving that template certain data via res.locals. I guess the point of unit testing these controllers wouldn't be the actual html (since the specifics of the layout can change), but whether given a certain request, the controller passes the right output to the template.

I don't understand how I'm supposed to test this though since the controller function doesn't actually "output" anything so how am I supposed to determine what it did in a test script? Also, I don't know how to give it a specific input because it's input is an HTTP request that's gone through a bunch of other middleware in the pipeline.

Here's an example of a controller:

```js
    function index_post(req, res, next) {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
    
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.locals.error = errors.array()[0];
        res.locals.email_value = req.body.email;
        res.locals.password_value = req.body.password;
        return res.render("login");
      }
   
      res.locals.message = 'You logged in';
      res.render('success');
    };
```

Outside the context of the Express pipeline, I'm not sure how to give it test inputs (normally it's reading properties from req as placed by previous middleware) and how to get access to the output (res.locals and what template it renders)
e.g I'd want to test that given a request with a valid email and password, `index_post` renders the "success" template and `res.locals` contains a `message` property with value. (I don't need to do do it in exactly the way I just mentioned, but I'm assuming unit testing a controller would require asserting those two facts.)

Comment: please provide some code so the community can help you better. Generally speaking, you need to provide a fake payload to your controller, then execute it and assert on the results (stub out anything else that you don't wana test).

Comment: So basically I pass the controller  a bunch of fake objects that share the same interface as the real objects, but since I made them I can look inside them afterwards to infer what the controller did?

Comment: yes exactly, thats the idea.

Comment: That makes so much sense now. Thanks for your help!